# Isomorphism of a theory

Tags: logic

So, I'm preparing for an exam and there are various examples regarding isomorphism, what I don't get at all. I don't seem to be able to grasp the idea of isomorphism. Could you explain please how does it look, how can I imagine isomorphic groups?

I'm going to throw here an example, maybe if you could explain it on this, that would be great.

> Find the spectrum of the theory $T = \{R(x,x),R(x,y) \rightarrow
> > R(y,x),R(x,y) \land R(y,z) \rightarrow R(x,z),\phi \}$ where $\phi$
>   means that there are 5 elements.

**Definition of the spectrum:** A spectrum of the theory $T$ is given by the number $I(K,T)$ of mutually nonisomorphic models of $T$ for every cardinality $K$.

Please don't just give me a link to the definition of isomorphism. I've seen that and I don't understand it. Other than that, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the question were more informal and just said "find the number of different models of size $K$" would you be able to do it?

Comment: No. That's my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first axiom says that the relation $R$ is reflexive, the second that it is symmetric, and the third that it is transitive. In other words, the first three axioms specify that $R$ is an equivalence relation. Thus, $T$ is the theory of equivalence relations on a $5$-element set.

An equivalence relation on a set $X$ is completely determined by its equivalence classes, which are a partition of $X$. Conversely, each partition of $X$ corresponds to a unique equivalence relation on $X$ having the elements of that partition as its equivalence classes.

Let’s take $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Consider the partitions

$$\big\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\}\big\}\tag{1}$$

and

$$\big\{\{1,3,5\},\{2,4\}\big\}\;:\tag{2}$$

The bijection $h:X\to X$ defined by

$$\begin{align*}
&1\mapsto 1\\
&2\mapsto 3\\
&3\mapsto 5\\
&4\mapsto 4\\
&5\mapsto 2
\end{align*}$$

is one of several that transforms the first partition into the second. Now let $R_1$ be the equivalence relation whose equivalence classes form the partition $(1)$, and let $R_2$ be the equivalence relation whose equivalence classes form the partition $(2)$. (For instance, $\langle 1,2\rangle\in R_1$, and $\langle 2,4\rangle\in R_2$.) You should check that for all $x,y\in X$, $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_1$ if and only if $\langle h(x),h(y)\rangle\in R_2$, and hence that $h$ is an isomorphism between the equivalence relation $\langle X,R_1\rangle$ and the equivalence relation $\langle X,R_2\rangle$.

If you understand that example, you should be able to see that whether two equivalence relations $\langle X_1,R_1\rangle$ and $\langle X_2,R_2\rangle$ are isomorphic depends only on the numbers and sizes of their equivalence class partitions. In the example each of the partitions $(1)$ and $(2)$ has $2$ classes, one of size $3$ and one of size $2$. Thus, we can simply match up the elements of $X$ with a bijection that matches up the $3$-element class of $(1)$ with the $3$-element class of $(2)$, and likewise for their $2$-element classes.

It isn’t necessary that the underlying sets be the same, either: they just need to have the same number of elements – $5$ in this problem – partitioned into the same number of pieces of the same sizes. For instance, if $Y=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$, the equivalence relation $R_3$ whose classes are the elements of the partition

$$\big\{\{a,d,e\},\{b,c\}\big\}$$

of $Y$ also has a $3$-element class and a $2$-element class, and the bijection $g:X\to Y$ defined by

$$\begin{align*}
&1\mapsto a\\
&2\mapsto d\\
&3\mapsto e\\
&4\mapsto b\\
&5\mapsto c
\end{align*}$$

is an isomorphism of the equivalence relations $\langle X,R_1\rangle$ and $\langle Y,R_2\rangle$.

The point of all this is that the *isomorphism class* of a model of $T$ is completely determined by the sizes of its equivalence classes. If we list them in non-decreasing order, we’re looking at tuples of positive integers whose sum is $5$, since each of the $5$ elements must appear in exactly one equivalence class. The examples that I’ve used so far have all been of type $\langle 2,3\rangle$: they have one equivalence class of size $2$ and one of size $3$. The entire list of possibilities isn’t hard to write down.

- The type $\langle 5\rangle$ has a single equivalence class: everything in the underlying set is related to everything in the underlying set.
- There are two types with two equivalence classes, $\langle 1,4\rangle$ and $\langle 2,3\rangle$.
- There are two types with three equivalence classes, $\langle 1,1,3\rangle$ and $\langle 1,2,2\rangle$.
- There is one type with four equivalence classes, $\langle 1,1,1,2\rangle$.
- There is one type with five equivalence classes, $\langle 1,1,1,1,1\rangle$; this is the relation of *equality* on the underlying set, in which each element is related only to itself.

Thus, there are altogether seven isomorphism classes of equivalence relations on a $5$-element set.

There are no models of $T$ of any cardinality other than $5$.

In general you’re going to have to think about exactly what makes two models of a given theory isomorphic. In the case of equivalence relations, it’s the number and sizes of the parts of the corresponding partition of the underlying set into equivalence classes. For another theory it will likely be something very different. In every case the key is recognizing what makes two models of the theory structurally identical – in effect the same model, merely with the names of the elements changed in some one-to-one fashion.

Comment: Holy! This is a really nice explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @Wanderer: You’re welcome (and thank *you*).

Answer (score 2):

**This answer doesn't address your specific example, which Brian M. Scott's answer has carefully analyzed; it just tries to give an intuitive explanation of "isomorphism."**

---

Consider a language $\mathcal{L}$ with a single unary relation symbol, $U$. A structure in this language - an $\mathcal{L}$-structure - is just a pair $\mathcal{M}=(X; Y)$, where $X$ is some set (the *domain* of the structure) and $Y$ is a subset of $X$ (the part of $X$ named by $U$; basically, for $a\in X$, $U(a)$ holds if and only if $a$ is in $Y$). This set $Y$ is usually denoted by "$U^\mathcal{M}$," the *interpretation of the symbol $U$ in the structure $\mathcal{M}$.*

Now, consider the following two $\mathcal{L}$-structures:

- $\mathcal{M}$: the domain is $\{1, 2, 3\}$, and $U^\mathcal{M}=\{1\}$.
- $\mathcal{N}$: the domain is $\{4, 5, 2015\}$ and $U^\mathcal{N}$={2015}$.

These structures "look the same" - they both have three elements, exactly one of which satisfies $U$. In fact, if I didn't tell you the *names* of the elements of the structures, you wouldn't be able to distinguish them.

The term "isomorphism" is how we make this precise. Two structures $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are isomorphic if I can take $\mathcal{M}$, rename its elements (without changing any of their properties), and wind up with $\mathcal{N}$. Formally, we ask for a function $f:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathcal{N}$ which is bijective and a homomorphism.

---

My $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ above are silly; there are some surprising examples of isomorphisms out there. For example, the structures $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $((0, \infty), \times)$ are isomorphic; if I take a real number $r$, and replace it with $e^r$, this describes an isomorphism from $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ to $((0, \infty), \times)$.